# Typescript refactoring function

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, refactoring, angular5

Im using sonar and im getting a bug smell in my last if with the variable **i++**. I need to refactor this code someway so its not so redundant:

```
private getDetailedUsageUrl(startDate: string, endDate: string, trafficType: string){
    this.logsProvider.debugLog(this.logTag, 'getDetailedUsageUrl');

    let url = this.detailedUsageServiceUrl;
    let i = 3;

    if (startDate !== null){
      url += 'startDate=$' + i;    
      i++;    
    }

    if(endDate !== null){
      url += '&endDate=$' + i;
      i++;
    }

    if (trafficType !== null){
      url += '&trafficType=$' + i;
      i++;
    }
    return url;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you?

```
function getDetailedUsageUrl(startDate: string | null = null, endDate: string | null = null, trafficType: string | null = null): string {
    // this.logsProvider.debugLog(this.logTag, 'getDetailedUsageUrl');
    // let url = this.detailedUsageServiceUrl;
    const url = 'http://example.com/?'
    const offset = 3;

    let para: any = {
         startDate,
         endDate,
         trafficType
    };

    para = Object.keys(para)
        .filter((key) => para[key] !== null)
        .map((key, inx) => key + '=$' + (offset + inx));

    return url + para.join('&');
}

// http://example.com/?startDate=$3&endDate=$4&trafficType=$5
console.log(getDetailedUsageUrl('a', 'b', 'c'));

// http://example.com/?endDate=$3&trafficType=$4
console.log(getDetailedUsageUrl(null, 'b', 'c'));

// http://example.com/?startDate=$3&trafficType=$4
console.log(getDetailedUsageUrl('a', null, 'c'));

// http://example.com/?startDate=$3&endDate=$4
console.log(getDetailedUsageUrl('a', 'b', null));
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQCLoIYwDaoAmAqgM7ZrEBOeAFKVNlZtlKgFyINUxjKIAfRGBB48iALzDReADSJUYQhlYcuUHn0HSxknXMQbswYDAgAVAJ4AHNd178hI3VOd4AlJ3taA3gChEQMQAemDDAAsYUgA6PDhkUgAFKjgANxhCVCpozIAjEGQAGXjaKEiYuORzCnkAcjRMHHwiMgpUajxa9wBuAKDQxAIoRBAaPTKonKaCEnI0AGUs9Ih2ml6gwfQRsala8Kgoa3ZQ1AAPbABbawJoiDgL4IB+Wr7AocQ4E1ItqQBmXtem2G1iY2E42DAlj0-g2sIYTBYbFkgNhimUqmRsI2RhMZistkBAF91ljEICQVRsHoAPK5ABWqGg0QA1qhLKRaBTsO4UUFoqY8GwqLRaKzLO5JAA+RBcgDaYoAuogAIQSVwyHmkxDRC7YawisXyXinCUSaVixAAakQtQkABJalbELRPsBvsNrcb3D0-ICqOhRkhRuJrVzonS4LxaLUAGRdXqE30DfaHY7BM6Xa6oW73J7w5gqNj234xtGF1D2gAsMZxpgsNgrdoArH47mBSHAbpVaA0sIxmrM2h1o9hanVcmObRAuj6-MmDkcTucrjc7g9HmXVMWa5TcfXbFXWwgO12Sr3pi05qs6G5x5PatPvQD56ml5nV7nHvnEY2S7W8Q2h5tie2bdue-YzK0lA0COk63lOM7PmEKaLumy5Zjm67fuW26bkWdqVke7adqBZ7oH2uCQVew61KOd7yG4T5AA)